# Is there a way to add a member to a card on a board which he is not a member of?

Tags: trello

We have been using Trello quite extensively in my organisation, trying to reduce e-mail clutter.
We have several "team-specific" boards and a single "executive" board, where a few of us discusses other teams.

Is there a way for us to easily add a person to a card located in our board, even though the person is not a member of the "executive" board? The person should be able to see only this card, similarly as if we had an e-mail discussion and added another person to it?

This is becoming a significant obstacle to us, so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I'm pretty sure that there's no way to do that, and the person has to be a member to see a card on the board, unless the board is public/open to your whole organization.

Answer (score 1):

At this point, only board members can be added to cards. Here's a link to a [Trello Help Article](http://help.trello.com/customer/portal/articles/1024320-adding-a-member-to-a-card) on the topic.

---

If you're contemplating a workaround, you can try [sharing links](http://help.trello.com/customer/portal/articles/1529455-sharing-links-to-cards-and-boards) to cards within exclusive boards.

Steps:

- Create a card to track the discussion on the Executive Board
- Create a new board with the members consisting of the Executives and the Team Member(s).
- On the new board, add a card and assign the Team Member(s) and Executives

Now, either,

- Link the card on this exclusive board to the card created in the first step.

*or*

- Link the exclusive board to the card created in the first step.